# Why is a directory referenced as a classpath resource null if the directory is empty?

Tags: java, maven

I've got the following unit test class, which referenced some test data files as classpath resources:

```
package com.altanqa.project.parser;

public class ParserTest {
    private static final URL VALID_DIR = ParserTest.class.getResource("testData-VALID");
    private static final URL INVALID_DIR = ParserTest.class.getResource("testData-INVALID");
    private static final URL MISSING_DIR = ParserTest.class.getResource("testData-MISSING");
    // ...
}
```

The directory structure referenced here looks like this:

```
src/test/java/com/altanqa/project/parser
    ParserTest.java
src/test/resources/com/altanqa/project/parser
    testData-VALID
        data
            test-data.txt
    testData-INVALID
        data
            test-data.txt
    testData-MISSING
        data
```

The Parser under test takes a directory, and knows to look in it for `data/testData.txt`. The test class here runs the parser, giving it valid data, invalid data, and missing data, to check that the parser deals with each situation correctly. Valid and invalid data works fine, but the `MISSING` URL is null. If I put a different file (say, `a.txt`) in `test-data-MISSING`, the URL is properly initialised, but without any files in the directory, it is null. Is this a peculiarity of the class loader? Is there a way around it, i.e. to have the `MISSING_DIR` URL initialise correctly, even with nothing in its subdirectory?

Thank you!

Comment: Check if `testData-MISSING/data` has been copied by Maven or your IDE to `target/test-classes` or `out/test-classes`

Comment: That'll be the issue then... You're right - it's not getting copied at the moment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to Boris for highlighting that this is a Maven issue, rather than anything with the Java. The `maven-resources-plugin` needs to be configured to include empty directories when copying resources. In the pom:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      ...
      <configuration>
        <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
      </configuration>
      ...
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```